# Одного знака мало? «Прокурор» добавит!

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, знаки

Один «золотой» знак «прокурор» (500 полезных тревог) честно «заработан» мною [2016/01/20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal).

А где-то с полчаса назад у меня один за другим появились ещё три (цифрой: 3) знака «прокурор»:

[image]

и общее количество «золотых» знаков стало 13 (вместо «положенных» десяти).

Мне лишних «прокуроров» не надо! исправьте, пожалуйста, «глюк».

Comment: Вам министра юстиции подавай?

Comment: @avp, ежели чего, готов взять поклонскими.

Comment: Однако, в профиле у вас Прокурор перечислен один раз - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal?userid=178576

Comment: @Nofate, на то он и глюк. общее количество «золота» [в профиле — десять](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin?tab=badges&sort=class). а на «счётчиках» (как в верхней строке, так и в профиле) — тринадцать.

Comment: Бота прям разорвало на значки, я смотрю. Мне выдали второго "Сыщика" за удаленное (!) сообщение. Похоже, что в тот же момент.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разработчики обновляли систему присуждения знаков и [сделали несколько ошибок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/135201). Насколько понимаю, в течение суток дубликаты знаков должны исчезнуть.

Comment: Ух-ты. А у них прокурор, это маршал... :)

Comment: @intro94 Маршалы в США не сидят на месте. Они [разыскивают обвиняемых и обеспечивает выполнение решений суда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90). В фильме "Беглец" за героем Харрисона Форда гонялся как раз "маршал Соединённых Штатов". [Томми Ли Джонс](http://soft-fs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/00132661.jpg) за эту роль Оскара получил.

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, не могу понять, зачем это разъяснение. Я знаю, кто такие маршалы в США. Я имел ввиду, интересно выходит, что на enSO знак называется "маршал", а у нас "прокурор". :)

Comment: @intro94 Просто образ из фильма вспомнился. Гораздо более клёвый образ, чем от слова "прокурор".

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, вероятно, с дурной компанией вы связались, раз у вас слово «прокурор» не вызывает ассоциации с [вполне реальным человеком](http://ria56.ru/uploads/posts/820x460_tr/36909.jpg).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Видимо, я слишком давно не смотрел телевизор... Теперь понимаю, что слово "рецидивист" может звучать нежно :)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, *Видимо, я слишком давно не смотрел телевизор* — лет двадцать, как я? // а те или иные ассоциации со словами — это, конечно, дело сугубо персональное.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да-да. Телевизор, VHS, одноголосный перевод...

Comment: @intro94 "пристав", возможно, отражает лучше, но "прокурор" звучит более угрожающе :)

Comment: @Кнопкатык `оперативник`